# extract 2 variables into a class automatically. (IntelliJ)

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

Maybe I ask for too much magic, but who knows :-)

I would like to extract 2 variables into a class with 2 variables and let the IDE doing all the refactoring. Is this possible ?

old:

```
class badStart(){

    private float positionX;
    private float positionY;
<other stuff>

}
```

refactored:

```
class badStart(){
    private corrdinate;
    <other stuff>
}

class coordinate(){
    private float positionX;
    private float positionY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Refactor -> Extract -> Delegate`.